# C# Invisible table values?

Tags: c#, winforms, select, datagridview, invisible

I am developing an Attendance Monitoring System and I have created a button which selects data from my access table with from and to values from two datetimepicker now if I press the button it selects the data from the database but the values are invisible, you have to click the column or row for it to show up, I don't know why, i didn't change the properties I even created a new datagridview but it's still the same, same with other PCs, here's my code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT [EmployeeID],[Firstname],[Lastname],[InDate],[InTime],[OutTime],[HoursWorked] FROM TimeinTimeout WHERE InDate between @1 AND @2";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString());
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Update();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            connection.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/animated gif demonstrating the issue? I could think of row style with weird colors (e.g. white on white).

Comment: Is this Winform, WPF or ASP.Net?

Comment: I agree with Sinatr, your comment _you have to click the column or row for it to show up_ ...confirms the data is there, so I would take a closer look at the `DataGridViews` styling for that column or cell. Just a guess.

Comment: Yes, the data is there but you have to click it for it show up, what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines of code:

```
dataGridView1.Update();  
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Hang on you haven't set the `connection`'s connection string. Typically it would be like this: `connection.Open(connectionString);`.

Comment: Yes. A question for you, in design time does setting the DataGridView AutoGenerateColumns property to false; make a difference?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but I'll try tomorrow

Comment: I solved the problem, I just searched for codes that changed the table color and font color like what Sinatr said. from white to white to white to black. Thanks for all your help guys, I just passed my defense yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `Databind()` after you set the data source (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Clarification, only ASP.Net requires the `DataBind()`

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, I did remove the .update and .refresh but it's still the same, this is in winforms